# iOS 7 doesn't launch application because of frame changes and adding subview to a view

Tags: objective-c, layout, uinavigationcontroller, frame, ios7

I just updated my iPad to iOS 7 and noticed that my app doesn't run. I put a breakpoint in `AppDelegate`  (I added custom code there), and found that it stucks here

```
   [storeView addChildViewController:navigationController];
    storeView.nav=navigationController;
    CGRect fr = storeView.view.frame;
    fr.size.height -= 49;
    navigationController.view.frame = fr;
    [storeView.view addSubview:navigationController.view];
```

When I comment these lines app launches fine. I understand that this is related to layout changes, but I could not find any solution for this. Even when I leave uncommented only the last line it still hangs without any error message. Any suggestions?

EDIT: I think there is something wrong with `addChildViewController`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you messing around with the view hierarchy from outside, when you already have a parent-child relationship between the two viewcontrollers?

Comment: does that make sense? In any case there exists a problem, and I still cannot find out where

Comment: Solved...The problem was in `[storeView addChildViewController:navigationController];` I don't know why it couldn't come up with it...